# Gatsby shows page not found and then loads the content of the page on

Tags: gatsby, wp-graphql

I'm not really sure where the problem is, I'm using amazon cloud, s3 bucket to host the website with cloudfront and WordPress as CMS

I thought Gatsby will create a static page but it looks like is injecting the content, the homepage looks ok but any other page it has this problem

I've been reading on forums, removing plugins but I haven't found a solution to this,
you guys can check for example https://londonfilmpremieres.com/the-sandman/ on a slow 3g connection

This is my **gatsby-config.js**

```
/**
 * Configure your Gatsby site with this file.
 *
 * See: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-config/
 */

require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
})

console.log(
  `This WordPress Endpoint is used: '${process.env.WORDPRESS_API_URL}/graphql'`
)

module.exports = {
  /* Your site config here */

  siteMetadata: {
    title: `London Film Premieres `,
    description: `With The latest upcoming film premieres in london. Exclusive celebrities photos and videos on the red carpet, interviews trailers and more!`,
    siteUrl: `${process.env.SITE_URL}`,
    image: "london-film-premieres.png",

  },

  plugins: [
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager",
      options: {
        id: "xxxxxx",
        includeInDevelopment: false,
      },
    },
 
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
      options: {
        url: `${process.env.WORDPRESS_API_URL}/graphql`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-feed`,
      options: {
        query: `
          {
            site {
              siteMetadata {
                title
                description
                siteUrl
                site_url: siteUrl
              }
            }

            allWpPost{
              nodes{
                title
                excerpt
                date
                link
                slug
                acf_details{
                  simpleplot
                }
              }
            }         
          }
        `,
        feeds: [
          {
            serialize: ({ query: { site, allWpPost } }) => {
              return allWpPost.nodes.map(node => {
                return Object.assign(
                  {},
                  {
                    title: node.title,
                    description: node.acf_details.simpleplot,
                    date: node.date,
                    url: `${process.env.SITE_URL}/${node.slug}/`,
                    guid: `${process.env.SITE_URL}/${node.slug}/`,
                  }
                )
              })
            },
            query: `
              {
                allWpPost {
                      nodes {
                        title
                        slug
                        acf_details {
                          simpleplot
                        }
                        date
                    }
                  }
              }
            `,
            output: "/rss.xml",
            title: "London film premieres - RSS Feed",
          },
        ],
      },
    },
      `gatsby-plugin-sass`,
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,

    `gatsby-plugin-zopfli`,
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
  ],
}
```

**gatsby-node.js**

```
const createHomePage = require("./create/createHomePage")
const createPages = require("./create/createPages")
const createPost = require("./create/createPost")

exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql, reporter }) => {
  await createHomePage({ actions, graphql, reporter })
  await createPages({ actions, graphql, reporter })
  await createPost({ actions, graphql, reporter })
}
```

**createPages.js**

```
module.exports = async ({ actions, graphql, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const { PostTemplateFragment } = require("../graphql/fragments.js")
  const pageTemplate = require.resolve("../src/templates/page-template.js")

  return graphql(
    `
      ${PostTemplateFragment}
      query MyQuery {
        allWpPage(filter: { isFrontPage: { eq: false } }) {
          nodes {
            id
            uri
            title
            content
          }
        }
        allWpPost {
          nodes {
            ...PostTemplateFragment
          }
        }
      }
    `
  ).then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
      throw result.errors
    }

    const pages = result.data.allWpPage.nodes
    const posts = result.data.allWpPost.nodes

    pages.forEach(node => {
      createPage({
        path: node.uri,
        component: pageTemplate,
        context: {
          id: node.id,
          page: node,
          posts,
          postSearchData: {
            allPosts: posts,
            options: {
              indexStrategy: "Prefix match",
              searchSanitizer: "Lower Case",
              TitleIndex: true,
              AuthorIndex: true,
              SearchByTerm: true,
            },
          },
        },
      })
      reporter.info(`page created:  ${node.uri}`)
    })
  })
}
```

my `page-template.js` it's just a normal file fetching data no other logic involve

```
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

export const query = graphql`
  query ($id: String) {
    wpPage(id: { eq: $id }) {
      title
      content
    }
  }
`

const PageTemplate = props => {
  const {
    pageContext: {
      postSearchData: { allPosts, options },
    },
  } = props

  const page = props.data.wpPage

  return (
    <Layout posts={allPosts} engine={options}>
      <h1 dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: page.title }} />
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: page.content }} />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default PageTemplate
```

I think I need to change something on gatsby-node but not sure exactly what could I do.

Answer (score 0):

This may not help or it might. But it's worth looking at in the meantime probably.

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/previews-deploys-hosting/deploying-to-s3-cloudfront/

Secondly,

checkout out the structure in the plugin's starter tutorial here: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/docs/tutorials/creating-a-new-site-from-a-starter.md

it's maybe a better structure for you to model after? In my opinion, the flow of the components could be refactored.

Lastly,

I'm a little confused why you have a page-template.js for. You're creating pages with the post-template. isn't that enough?
Like, after a user types in the search bar and gets a result to pop up under it, when they click that, wouldn't you just use the the  to reference to the post-template page that you create by doing something like <Link to=`${uri}` >?

Also,

You appear to being using Layout component in your templates, right?
If so, you should use the gatsby-browser.js and import the layout there so that it doesn't have to recreate the layout at every page, it'll just change whatever the children are within it. I believe it's the wrappageelement that's useful here. You should include it in the gatsby-ssr.js file too.

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/#wrapPageElement

https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/

AND...
there is always the option of using a different CMS. I personally enjoy hygraph.com (formerly called GraphCMS). It's a lot easier to use in my opinion and sources really easily in and is well supported.

If you could ever provide a way to clone this repo that'd be helpful for me personally so I could run something locally and see if it produces the same results.

Sorry I can't be of more help at the moment.